# Airflow - generate DAG from custom object

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using airflow 1.10.3. I am trying to create a class that I can instantiate multiple times to generate DAGs for me. Here is a simplified example:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator


class DagClass:

    def __init__(self, dag_id):
        self.dag_id = dag_id


    def test_function():
        print("test 1")

    def test_function2():
        print("test 2")


    def generate_dag(self):
        dag = DAG(self.dag_id)

        task1 = PythonOperator(
                  task_id="test",
                  python_callable=self.test_function,
                  provide_context=True,
                  dag=dag
                )

        task2 = PythonOperator(
                task_id="test2",
                python_callable=self.test_function2,
                provide_context=True,
                dag=dag
                )

        task1.set_downstream(task2)

        return dag
```

Then, I try to use that class to create a DAG in another file here:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from dynamic_dag_test.dag_class import DagClass

dag_class = DagClass('test_dynamic_dag')

dag = dag_class.generate_dag()

globals()['test_dynamic_dag'] = dag
```

However if I do that, I won't get any errors, but my DAG will never show up in the web UI. BUT, if I instead get rid of the class and just directly import the function from another file, it works fine.

Does anyone know why this is and how I can get it to work with the class? Thanks!

Comment: since you are passing `dag_id` in constructor (`__init__`) of `DagClass`, you will have to create a new instance of DagClass every time you want to create a new dag. (since two dags can't have same dag_id) The workaround would be to simply accept `dag_id` as a param in `generate_dag()` function itself.

Comment: Have you tried to put : ```globals()['test_dynamic_dag'] = dag ``` inside the generate_dag() method?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: we actually did get this to work with the code laid out above. One problem we ran into was if you removed the DAG import, it stopped working for some reason. So we had to be sure that stayed in there and it ended up being fine.

Comment: I had the same issue, but once I added the DAG import statement to all the dag files, the scheduler was able to find the dags

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the [comment of David Schuler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992333/airflow-generate-dag-from-custom-object/67019045#comment105868050_57992333) as well with Airflow 1.10.1. We had to put the import statement (`from airflow import DAG`) at the top of the Python file.